# Using OR operator in Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

Let me explain my scenarios. I'm building a multi site umbraco site. I got two type of homepage content type alias. (Assume XXXX and YYYY). I'm using `var homePage` in my common `NavMain.cshtml` partial view. How can I achieve something like following

```
var homePage = Model.Root().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.Alias == "XXXX" || x => x.ContentType.Alias == "YYYY");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```cs
var homePage = Model.Root().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.Alias == "XXXX" || x.ContentType.Alias == "YYYY");
```

---

See the following article for the correct syntax: [Expression lambdas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#expression-lambdas)

Comment: Tried, It throwing a syntax error

Comment: @troshan: Seems like the error caused by the wrong syntax. You used twice the `=>` sign (lambda expression).